# Rails 3 I18: translation missing: da.datetime.distance_in_words.about_x_hours  

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I get this error in view:

```
translation missing:
da.datetime.distance_in_words.about_x_hours
```

My da locale file: http://pastie.org/2944890

My view:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.new, konkurrancer.udtraekkes) %>
```

I have added this to my application.rb:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :da
```

If I remove the I18 config the helper does work on english.

**UPDATE:**

My configuration in my config/enviorments/devolpment.rb:

```
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  config.i18n.default_locale = :da
  config.i18n.locale = :da
```

My translation file in config/locales/da.yml:

```
da:
   datetime:
      distance_in_words:
         x_days:
            one: '1 day'
            other: '{{count}} dage'
```

And I get this error view:

```
translation missing:  da.datetime.distance_in_words.x_days
```

Answer (score 3):

You are close - all you have to do is fix the indentation in your locale file.
Starting at line #8 to the end of the file, increase the indentation by one unit.
This will allow Rails to resolve da[:datetime][:distance_in_words][:about_x_hours] 
to the proper value.

Comment: Yep, Spotted it that much quicker!

Comment: I could make a pastie but I don't know what you are trying to do with your particular configuration.  Just make sure that your indentation is correct by comparing your file with this correct one https://raw.github.com/clemens/i18n_demo_app/master/config/locales/en.yml

Comment: I have updated my question with a new try that also is not working.

Comment: I don't see your latest locale file, but if you have updated it so that the format is correct, you could try changing da: to "da":  Use this default file as the authoritative template: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml#L51.  The last thing to check would be to make sure that your indentations in the locale file are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
distance_in_words:
  x_days: "%{count} days"
```

or

```
distance_in_words:
  x_days:
    one: "1 day"
    other: "%{count} days"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the samples here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Answer (score 0):

The locale file has a problem at line#8, you are putting time key and all keys mentioned after this, are coming in under it time. Also there is one more time key at line#28 i.e. line#8 is added by mistake. try to remove line#8 and test it.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your `config/application.rb`

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

create file `da.yml` into `config/locales` thus getting your file: `config/locales/da.yml`

and now add into `da.yml` the information in this url: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/da.yml

now it's ok!